# Draw random binom dependent on individual variable and predefined group risk

Tags: r, probability

I'm trying to simulate exposure data in a group of people, and then to have a boolean conditional on the data. So say this is my simulated exposure data:

```
x <- rlnorm(2000)
```

I then want to generate a 1 or 0 for each person dependent on the value of x. I  can simply define the `max(x)' as P==1 and lesser values as a proportion thereof:

```
prob <- x / max(x)
y <- rbinom( n=length(x), 1, prob=prob)
> table(y)
y
   0    1 
1900  100
```

However this is not really what I want. I would like to also be able to set an overall population risk for the group, say 30% (so `risk = 0.3'), such that individual risk depends on x but the total group risk =0.3. At the end I want 30% of the population to have y==1, but with an individual probability dependent on the value of x. I'm at a loss as how to achieve this - any help appreciated.

**Update:**
Taking a hint from @B Williams answer below, I've written a short optimiser function:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = rlnorm(2000))
df1$prob <- df1$x / max(df1$x)
risk = 0.3

optimize_prob <- function(prob, risk, delta = 0.01, tol = 0.02, max_iter = 400, mult=1){

    prob1 <- prob

    for( i in 1: max_iter){    
        y <- rbinom( n=length(prob1), 1, prob=prob1)
        meas_risk <- sum(y==1) / length(y)
        if( abs(risk - meas_risk) > tol) {
            sign <- as.numeric((risk - meas_risk) >= 0)
            prob1 <- prob1 + (sign * delta) + (prob1 *delta * mult)
            # prob1's must lie between 0 & 1
            prob1 <- ifelse(prob1 > 1, 1, prob1)
            prob1 <- ifelse(prob1 < 0, 0, prob1)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    msg <- paste0("Iterations: ", i)
    print(msg)
    out <- cbind(prob1, y)
    return(out)
}

df1 <- data.frame(df1, optimize_prob( df1$prob, risk, mult=3))
df1$y <- as.factor(df1$y)
table(df1$y)
```

This more or less achieves the result I want. However, if anyone knows a neater way of doing this I'd much appreciate suggestions. Also any efficiency improvements to the above appreciated as I will be running it alot if all goes to plan.

Comment: "individual probability dependent on the value of x" -- how is y supposed to be related to x?

Comment: Yeah part of the problem here is I'm not sure how to put this in words. Basically what I want to have is P (Y) proportional to x, but I also want to control the overall number that have y==1. Is that clearer ?

Comment: I think you'll have to more explicitly define 'proportional'. Strictly speaking I think `y <- as.numeric(x < quantile(x, .3))` satisfies '`y` is individually related to `x`, and total group proportion is 30%`, but i'm guessing that's not what you are looking for...

Comment: No because that solution is a) deterministic and b) non-continuous. I'm sorry I don't know how to explain it any better.

Comment: Isn't that just the same as @arvi1000 's solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand correctly what you are trying to do, but here is my guess.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = rlnorm(2000))
```

Pull out the top 600 (30% of 2000) values and get the minimum value

```
df %>% 
    mutate(prob = x/max(x)) %>%  
    top_n(600) %>% 
    summarise(min.value = min(prob)) -> out
```

Set the global probability based upon the minimum value

```
df %>% 
    mutate(prob = x/max(x),
             global = ifelse(prob > out$min.value, 1, 0)) %>% 
    summarise(one = sum(global))
```

Alternatively you could write a function and optimize it to get the "cutoff" value.

Comment: I'm sorry I have difficulty to understand the pipe operator I don't fully understand this code. But I'm thinking this is the business line: `ifelse(prob > out$min.value, 1, 0))` - yes? Again this is a value based cut off that I dont' want as its less stochastic. Thinking overnight - how would I do this manually? I though of the following. Run my line `rbinom( n=length(x), 1, prob=prob)`. Count the 1's. If overall rate not as desired then add or subtract a small value to every probability and recheck. Repeat to desired probability achieved. Perhaps you correct to write function & optimize.

Comment: I updated the question with an optimizer function that possibly solves the problem but at least makes thing clearer I hope.